# DOM loads an empty document - php

Tags: xml, dom, domdocument, php

i wrote the following code:

```
$xmldom = new DOMDocument();
$xmldom->load('http://www.robot-domestici.it/joomla/component/virtuemart/robot-domestici/robot-pulizia-casa?page=shop.feed');
```

but the document loaded is empty (this category don't contains any product) and the following error occurs:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Document is empty in http://www.robot-domestici.it/joomla/component/virtuemart/robot-domestici/robot-pulizia-casa?page=shop.feed, line: 1 in C:\Users\Jacopo\Dropbox\Tirocinio\xampp-portable\htdocs\sites\prova\cerca categorie2.php on line 73

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in http://www.robot-domestici.it/joomla/component/virtuemart/robot-domestici/robot-pulizia-casa?page=shop.feed, line: 1 in C:\Users\Jacopo\Dropbox\Tirocinio\xampp-portable\htdocs\sites\prova\cerca categorie2.php on line 73
```

and interrupt the execution. obviously the URL is generated dinamically and even the contents of the feed can change so i can't know wich URL will be empty. i've to do some check, but i can't figure out what i can do....
i'v tried to store the feed in a variable but it don't works:

```
$str=file_get_contents('http://www.robot-domestici.it/joomla/component/virtuemart/robot-domestici/robot-pulizia-casa?page=shop.feed');
if($str==='')
        return;
```

what can i do?

Comment: You will likely get an exception. Catch it. http://php.net/exception - Additionally  [`DOMDocument::$strictErrorChecking = false;`](http://www.php.net/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.stricterrorchecking)

Comment: i've tried to catch the exeception but it doesn't work, the warnings continues to show up... however i've noticed that those warnings have no effect on the execution that continues normally (i haven't noticed it before). now i simply suppress warnings with a "@"

thanks for the reply anyway :)

Comment: okay, in production, do error logging - not display. But apart from that general thing (which is true for all kind of errors), for loading the XML files with DOMDocument there is also another feature called libxml internal errors. I pick you the link of the duplicate question.